# Определение координат UIView при скролинге

Tags: objective-c

Доброго времени суток. Подскажите пожалуйста ка можно решить проблему.
Есть **UIView** на нем внизу по ширине экрана расположен скролл(горизонтальный), в скролле 6 картинок. По нажатию на кнопку нужно переместить картинку с правого верхнего угла на картинку которая находится в скролле. 
Нужно узнать координаты **UIView** которая находится в скролле относительно главного View.
Как то так. Извините что непонятно, не знаю ка описать лучше.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё верно, координаты картинок и не должны изменяться.

Вам нужно прибавлять к ним текущий contentOffset вашего скролла: свойство, показывающее смещение скролла от нулевой отметки.

```
CGFloat yourImageViewX = yourScrollView.contentOffset.x + yourImageView.frame.origin.x
```

Надеюсь, правильно понял ваш запрос.

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло.